# is there any way to get the return value from a method by using @selector except using double pointer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I don't want to use double pointer. I am using a function in simpler form as below.

```
-(NSString *) getName
{
    return name;
}
```

So what is the correct way to take the returned `NSString *`?

By using `@selector(getName)` i  am not able to get the returned value `name`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you calling the @selector method?

Comment: i am using it as
`[obj perfromSelector:@selector(getName)];`

Comment: @PranjalBikashDas : it is performing your selector on obj but where are you making an owner so that the value can be assigned?

Comment: @Tarun:
here is the full code.

`id obj;`
`SEL mySelector=@selector(getName);`
`if([obj respondToSelector:mySelector])`
`{`
`[obj perfromSelector:mySelector];`
`}`

now my question is how i can assign the returned the value.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `NSInvocation` object instance for calling a selector and resolving returned result.

Comment: and i want to say thank you..You have shown me a nice way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

`performSelector:` *does* give you the return value directly.

```
NSString * s = @"NEXT WE HAVE NUMBER FOUR, 'CRUNCHY FROG'.";
NSString * l = [s performSelector:@selector(lowercaseString)];
NSLog(@"%@", l);    // prints "next we have number four, 'crunchy frog'."
```